# Common symbol for PLL

Tags: symbol, pll

Is there a common symbol for PLLs, either for schematics or functional diagrams?

I need a symbol which would be easily recognized as a PLL, without having to draw the phase comparator, loop filter, and VCO separately.

Otherwise, I'll resort to just drawing a square and writing "PLL" inside.

Comment: Block with a PLL sounds good.

Comment: A box that says "PLL" can't be misunderstood, right?

Comment: From what I've seen the block is most commnly used.

Comment: @HarrySvensson  You wouldn't think so, but the presentation I'm working on uses the acronyms PL and PS a lot (for programmable logic and processing system, respectively). The extra "L" might easily be missed, so I was hoping to make it obvious with a symbol.

Comment: I'm going to have to agree with the others. A box with a label "PLL" is pretty ubiquitous... As far as an IEEE/IEC etc. standard, I don't think there is a symbol for it.

Comment: Well, this helps. Maybe I'll throw a ϕ inside it next to "PLL".

Comment: You should draw phi, inside a pad lock, inside an arrow going clockwise :) #MarketingTechniques

Comment: @KingDuken  And with that, I think we found our IEEE/IEC submission.